# How to inspect calendar elements - Chrome /android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, appium, mobile-website

I am using chrome dev tool to inspect web mobile elements. But I can't inspect calendar using chrome dev tool (chrome://inspect/#devices). It doesn't show up the calendar. I want to click 'Set' button on the calendar. but unable to find the lcator for that. Is there a way to find the locator on the calendar?
[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfdSb.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is an "Emulate a focused page" option in ChromeDevTools, did you try that?

Comment: I have enabled the 'Emulator focused page' and tried again. But still no difference. Calendar doesn;t show up for inspect elements.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is switching the context to NATIVE APP. Calendar can inspect via appium inspector and use native app locators to select the date. Once the date is selected switch context again to CHROMIUM/WEB.

```
    Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
        driver.context((String) contextNames.toArray()[1]);
        driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
```